# DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) implementation questions

Tags: exim, dkim

I am going to set-up DKIM on my server with Exim and have the following questions:

**Question 1**

My server hostname is `domain1.com` and the server is sending emails with:

```
Return-Path: <root@domain1.com>
envelope-from <root@domain1.com>, etc
```

However, all emails may contain different "from" addresses:

```
From: something2 <something2@domain2.com>
From: something3 <something3@domain3.com>
```

Should I create a DKIM key for `domain1.com` and sign all emails with this key or should I create DKIM keys for all domains used as "from" address?

**Question 2**

I send mail with my domains from my own server but at the same time I use my domains with Gmail.

What will happend if I create a DKIM key for my domain `domain1.com` and publish an appropriate DNS record? Emails sent from my server will be DKIM signed but emails sent with my domain from Gmail system will be not signed. Is it OK not to sign emails even if DKIM public key is published in DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to question #1, it is something of a judgement call, but I'd probably create keys for all the domains being used in the From addresses, and sign emails with the appropriate DKIM key.  This approach means that the From address and the DKIM authentication will be aligned.  That makes it easy to turn on DMARC at some point in the future.

As for question #2, you have a couple of options:

1. Just DKIM sign emails originating from your server.  Google-originating emails will not be signed.  They won't gain any benefit, but unless you turn on DMARC they shouldn't be penalized either
2. Turn on DKIM signing in Google Apps, and add the DKIM record alongside the one for your personal DKIM key.  DKIM keys are distinguished by selectors, which are domain prefixes used to specify different keys.  So you can have multiple DKIM keys (and multiple signing senders) sending email on a single domain.